# perform same operation as linux pipe in java?

Tags: java

How can I do the following in Java code (without invoking the shell directly - not using the pipe operator at all)?

```
echo path | ./app
```

Is this the same as starting the app and then writing to STDIN?

I want to be able to start a process from Java and destroy it (and not worry about child processes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), which wraps the [`Process` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) to start a process from your Java application, and grab its IO streams using [`Process#getInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29) and [`Process#getOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29).

Comment: then once I start the process I write to the Process Output Stream?

Comment: Yes. that's the idea. consider handling the other process IO in more than one thread.