# Escape character "|" error (Linux command)

Tags: java, linux, ffmpeg, escaping, character

I'm trying to run a Linux command in Java.

This is the command:

> "ffmpeg -i rtmp://192.168.1.112/garage/stream26g -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 64000 -s 480x320 -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -b 544k -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 5 -trellis 2 -refs 0 -coder 0 -me_range 16  -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 200k -maxrate 544k -bufsize 544k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 30 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -aspect 480:320 -g 30 -async 2 - | vod - 10 stream/stream26g/sample stream/stream26g/stream.m3u8 http://www.tshizerbia.com//video/ 5";

But it gives me an error:

> Unable to find a suitable output format for |

And I don't know what is the problem

I used this to run the command

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

If I put `\\|` in the string the message error is:

> Unable to find a suitable output format for \|

How can I escape this character? Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [perform same operation as linux pipe in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389632/perform-same-operation-as-linux-pipe-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a linux terminal command in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364315/execute-a-linux-terminal-command-in-java)

Comment: Unrelated to your current issue, but declaring each libx264 option is not recommended. That's what the encoding presets are for. Instead your command could be: `ffmpeg -i input -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -b:a 64k -s 480x320 -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -b:v 544k -maxrate 544k -bufsize 544k -level 30 -g 30 -async 2 -`. See the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide).

Answer (score 1):

Try quoting the pipe character.  I don't think it needs to be Java-escaped; I think it needs to be shell-quoted.  Of course then you'll have to Java-escape the double-quote characters:

```
...-async 2 - \"|\" vod - 10 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The pipe "|" is shell specific. Try executing it through a shell instead, something like

```
String[] bashCommand = {"/bin/bash", "-c", command};
```

and execute this bashCommand instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -i rtmp://192.168.1.112/garage/stream26g -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 64000 -s 480x320 -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -b 544k -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 5 -trellis 2 -refs 0 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 200k -maxrate 544k -bufsize 544k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 30 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -aspect 480:320 -g 30 -async 2 - \\| vod - 10 stream/stream26g/sample stream/stream26g/stream.m3u8 http://www.tshizerbia.com//video/ 5");
```

Comment: @syb0rg the question has been edited since to change from \ to \\

Comment: @MajidLAISSI The question was only edited to add code-quotes (backticks).  Without the code-quotes, Markdown renders a double backslash only once, because it treats the first one as an escape character.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping it with `\\|`. Works for Java, but I'm not sure specifically for linux command as you're asking.